# Is there a better way to convert a dict to string delimited by comma?

Tags: python

For example:

```
d = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3'}
```

I want to get ds as a str:

```
ds = 'a:1, b:2, c:3'
```

My conversion function:

```
 def convert_dict(my_dict):
        converted = ''
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            converted += key + ':' + value + '，'
        return converted[0:-1]
```

I suspect there should be a better and simpler way to do this.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python join sequence` into a search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d.items()` gives (key, value) so first create `key:value` using `map(':'.join, d.items())` then finally join them using `', '.join`

```py
', '.join(map(':'.join, d.items())) 

#'a:1, b:2, c:3'
```

NOTE: both key and value should be `str` if not u can use

```
', '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}:{x[1]}', d.items()))
```

Comment: This one is concise, though I don't know the usage of map(':'.join, d.items())

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: I would not use `map` `lambda` in place of a comprehension or generator expression. Instead I'd do `', '.join(f'{x[0]}:{x[1]}' for x in d.items())`

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. We can do it with comprehensions to make it a bit shorter. But your code is perfectly understandable as-is and is nothing to be ashamed of.

```
def convert_dict(my_dict):
  return ', '.join(f"{key}:{value}" for key, value in my_dict.items())
```

If you're using Python older than 3.5, you'll need to use `.format` rather than the `f""` string syntax I use in my example above.

Comment: This one is more understandable!

Comment: @marlon This one is also a little more flexible than the answer by Epsi95. Using the f-string will handle casting values to string, which would cause `":".join` to error out.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_d = ", ".join([":".join([str(k), str(v)]) for k, v in d.items()])
```

Comment: Hacking regex to manipulate `dict` string representations is probably not the best habit to be teaching new programmers. This will fail down the road when OP encounters a string that has an actual apostrophe in it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That is true, I was just addressing the simple case like OP showed in the example...and yeah, use a different approach than the most obvious ones.